# visual studio 2017 tab MIDL is missing in VC++ DLL project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, com-interop, midl, tlbexp

Any idea to generate TLB file for Visual C++ DLL porject please. My project does not have tab MIDL when loading Project Property.

[image]

Comment: Your project is probably not the type of project (for example an ATL DLL project has the MIDL tab) that instructs Visual Studio to add the MIDL tab. But midl is "just" a command line tool that you can invoke manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/invoking-the-midl-compiler

Comment: you are the man !!! recreated the MFC ATL project. thanks